# Laying out DIVs in a table-like manor in HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to figure out how to CSS-style my `DIV`'s in order to make a calendar view of some data.

Here is a screenshot of what I've got so far.

I'm using a table, with tr and five `TD`'s. Inside the `TD`'s I've added a `DIV` that has display: inline-block. Somewhat like this structure:

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><div></div></td>
        <td><div></div></td>
        <td><div></div></td>
        <td><div></div></td>
        <td><div></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div></div></td>
        <td><div></div></td>
        <td><div></div></td>
        <td><div></div></td>
        <td><div></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

It looks alright as long as there is no text inside the `DIV`, but when I add some text the grid is skewed, as seen in the picture.

[image]

I've tried different variants of `TABLE` vs `DIV`, but I just can get it do display correctly.

Do you have any suggestions as to how I can create this calendar view?

I don't want to use a calendar-plugin, since this is a part of a more complex resource-view I'm building.

Comment: Since you have tabular data and are using a table layout, are you sure you still want to use divs?

Comment: But why do you want to use divs instead of a table for this?

Comment: Hmm, not necessarily. But at a later stage I will probably need to have a little control over the text inside the td's, so I'm thinking that is easier when it's inside a div?

Comment: Tables are for laying out tabular data (which this is) and you can control the text all you like within a td. If you want to get specific on elements inside of the td, use a span. Spans are inline elements and shouldn't affect your layout, div are block level and will.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to align the divs in a table-like way using `text-align` and `vertical-align`, making sure you give each div a separate `id`.

**HTML**

```html
<div class="table" id="one"></div>
<div class="table" id="two"></div>
<div class="table" id="three"></div>
<div class="table" id="four"></div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.table{
    width: 45%;
    height: 45%;
    background-color: #efefef;
}
#one{
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#two{
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#three{
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#four{
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

try that and tell me if it is insufficient.

if you have more than 9 divs, use pixels for the alignment